# Webdriver não da erro porém também não abre o navegador

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome

Testei um código simples para fazer o webdriver abrir o Chrome, e foi realizado com sucesso, porém o codigo abaixo não da erro, porém não abre o navegador.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


class InstagramBOT:
 def _init_(self, username, password):
     self.username = username
     self.password = password
     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')


def login(self):
 driver = self.driver
 driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

 Raphaelbot = InstagramBOT('***', '***')
 raphaelbot.login()
```

Comment: olha a versao do webdriver no seu pc

Comment: O path está correto?

Comment: Qual é a mensagem do erro que apresenta?

Answer (score -1):

Já enfrentei esse mesmo erro, experimente instalar o webdriver numa variável
com essa lib `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager`

Seu código ficará assim:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

#CASO NÃO TENHA A LIB, IRÁ BAIXAR A LIB ATRAVÉS DO PIP E IMPORTARÁ
#USE ESSE TRY/EXCEPT NO PRIMEIRO USO, DEPOIS NÃO É MAIS NECESSÁRIO
#OU UTILIZE O TERMINAL PARA INSTALAR A LIB E PODE IMPORTAR NORMALMENTE
import os
try:
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
except:
    os.system("pip install webdriver-manager")
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


_webdriver=ChromeDriverManager().install() 

class InstagramBOT:
 def _init_(self, username, password):
     self.username = username
     self.password = password
     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(_webdriver)


def login(self):
 driver = self.driver
 driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

 Raphaelbot = InstagramBOT('***', '***')
 raphaelbot.login()
```

Meu sistema operacional é o Linux, se for Windows o seu, pesquise como usar essa lib webdriver-maneger se der erro na execução. Mas acredito que vai funcionar.